# In cocos2d, how do I capture multiple touches?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

As seen in the [documentation for CCResponder](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/Classes/CCResponder.html), multi-touch capturing is enabled by setting `multipleTouchEnabled = YES`, but the documentation says nothing about how to actually receive these multi-touches. The callbacks mentioned on the documentation page only captures a single touch.

So, in cocos2d-iphone v3.0, how do I capture multi-touches once `multiTouchEnabled` has been set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multi-touches the regular single-touch events (`touchBegan:withEvent:` etc) are simply called once for each touch.

The problem with this approach is that you don't know whether another touch event is coming after the current one, so you don't know whether it is a multi-touch and how many touches there are. You could create your own set, add each touch to the set, and postpone touch processing to the update: method where you process (and empty) the set of touches.

Currently v3 offers no way of receiving the touches of a multi-touch in a NSSet. You'd have to modify CCResponderManager.m to do this.

Comment: That sounds like an incredibly bad design decision. It makes it practically impossible to use CCResponder to generate a robust (!) multi-touch handling. I don't think it is a healthy pattern to alter the framework sources as it makes the app vulnerable for framework upgrades. Any ideas on how to capture a multitouch (for a pinch effect, if that makes a difference) without relying on CCResponder?

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue on github instead. I'm surprised myself that there doesn't seem to be a way to receive "touches" events, or maybe there is but it's just not obvious. As for standard gestures you should rely on UIGestureRecognizer anyway, and implementing custom recognizers is also an option to do multitouch handling.